# How do I add an object to a database in Knex where the object is the child of two parents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blogs, knex.js

I have the code below. Its a standard blog type of setup with users which have posts and comments. Comments are the child of both users and post . Posts belong just to users.  Im having a problem posting to comments table. IM not getting any errors  when using the insert function  , however, when I post a comment to the database nothing gets saved to the comments table . If i do a request to retrieve the comments table , the table still shows empty. What am i doing wrong here  .

```
server.post("/users/:id/posts/:id2/comments", async (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.params.id;
    const postID = req.params.id2;
    db("users")
        .where({ id: Number(userID)})
        .then((user) => {
            db('posts') .where({ id: Number(postID)})
                        .then((post) => {

                  //verify if post and user exists 
                if (post && user) {
                    req.body.content ? insertComment({
                            content: req.body.content,
                            user: userID,
                            post: postID
                        })
                            .then(
                                res.status(201).json(req.body)

                        )
                            .catch((err) => {
                                console.log(err);
                            })
                        : res.status(400).json({
                            errorMessage: "Please insert text .",
                        });
                } else {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        message: "user not found",
                    });
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                err,
                message: "Error processing request",
            });
        });
});


function insertComment(comment) {
    return db("comments").insert(comment).where({
        user: comment.user,
        post: comment.post
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since you're already using `async` function i'd first recommend to use `async/await`, second notice is that knex returns an array and not an object for example

```js
db("users")
        .where({ id: Number(userID)})
        .then((user) => {
            // user is an array
        });
```

---

you can chain a query with `.first()` to retrieve the first object and not an array
[image: Knex Documentation]

[Reference from knex documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-first)

---

using `async/await` could save you from callback hell

```js
server.post("/users/:id/posts/:id2/comments", async (req, res) => {
  const userID = req.params.id;
  const postID = req.params.id2;

  try {
    const user = await db("users").where("id", Number(userID)).first();
    const post = await db("posts").where("id", Number(postID)).first();

    if (post && user) {
      if (req.body.content) {
        await insertComment({
          content: req.body.content,
          user: userID,
          post: postID,
        });
        return res.status(201).json(req.body);
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errorMessage: "Please insert text .",
        });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "user or post not found",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      err,
      message: "Error processing request",
    });
  }
});

async function insertComment(comment) {
  return db("comments").insert(comment).where({
    user: comment.user,
    post: comment.post,
  });
}
```

---

**and if you have lots of relationships in your application you might find it useful if you want to use an ORM like [Objection](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) as it is built on knex.**